# Mathematician into Particle Physics master

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, string-theory, education, mathematics

This summer I'm ending my 4 years degree in Mathematics, and I'm considering a master in Particles physics and gravitation. My two options are this or a master in mathematics, in both cases in order to get a PhD in respective fields. Theoretical particle physics ( possibly strings, or something where I can take advantage of my pure mathematics degree) or in applied mathematics.

In order to go into the particle physics master, I'll have to take compulsory introduction courses (of Physics degree) of Quantum Physics, Quantum Mechanics, General Relativity and maybe also an introduction to Nuclear and Particle Physics (I'm waiting for the coordinator to tell me which ones specifically).

My question is, do you think there are other topics on physics that could be interesting for QFT, Strings etc... ?  If I'm told to do my master in two years instead of one because of the introduction courses, I'll consider assisting to other topics. In my degree I already did classical mechanics, electromagnetic fields and basic fluid dynamics. A bit of special relativity too.